# MeeGo v1.2 SDK download

Tags: nokia, meego, meego-harmattan

I'd like to develop some apps to my mobile device N9, but I can't actually find where to download MeeGo v1.2 SDK.

I tried developer.meego.com but there link broked.
I could just download for linux, but not for Win7 64x

Also tried other download sites, but there was all trojan warnings from antivurus.

Anybody can help out ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old Nokia QT SDKs are apparently still available at [Developer Wiki site](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Qt#Qt_SDK)